# Unsupported literal type class in Apache Spark in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following data:

```
    +---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
    |   time_stamp_0|sender_ip_1|receiver_ip_2|count|attack|
    +---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
    |06:10:55.881073|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   1 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881095|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   2 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881114|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   3 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881133|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   4 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881152|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   5 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881172|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   6 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881191|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   7 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881210|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   8 |     0|
```

I need to compare the total standard deviation on count column with itself (with count column) in my dataframe. Here is my code:

```
val std_dev=Dataframe_addcount.agg(stddev_pop($"count"))

val final_add_count_attack = Dataframe_addcount.withColumn("attack", when($"count" > std_dev , 0).otherwise(1))
```

However my problem is that, I got the following error:

```
Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset [stddev_pop(count): double]
```

Could you help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In my case it's because I used collect and didn't notice that I got an array of Row objects rather than an array of Strings.  You can't use the result of collect in a where clause of a data frame unless you unwrap the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in when and otherwise you should use values; not std_dev is a DataFrame.

You can get result:

```
val stdDevValue = std_dev.head().getDouble(0)

val final_add_count_attack = Dataframe_addcount.withColumn("attack", when($"count" > lit(std_dev), lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How should I convert the std_dev to double? Should I use another method to calculate the standard deviation? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, just a minor problem is that getAsDouble does't recognize in my intellij idea. :(

Comment: It's getDouble - I've fixed it

Comment: @T.Gawęda I am getting similar error while filtering ...how to fix it   ....  result_df.filter( col("indicator") === lit('N'))     .... ERROR ::: RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.lang.Character N

Comment: @user3252097 use "N" instead of 'N'

Comment: @T.Gawęda used thank you ....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727559/how-to-fix-assertionerror-assertion-failed-unsafe-symbol-unstable-child-of-n

Answer (score -2):

There would be some code related to constants where double quote is required, but code would have single quote or no quote. generally happens when you have `lit('0')`, correct it to `lit("0")`